How to reformulate negative power of posynomial as a geometric programming constraint?
Currently, I am working as a network optimization engineer. From what I see, most of my optimization task can be fulfil effectively by using Geometric Programming (GP). However, I am running into a strange situation where I cannot find anyway to turn a simple linear constraint into form due to its reverse sign.
Therefore, my question is:
How to formulate this constraint as GP constraint ${x_1} + {x_2} + ... + {x_n} \ge 1$ ?
My effort so far is this $\frac{1}{{{x_1} + {x_2} + ... + {x_n}}} \le 1$ but I dont know how to keep going ?
The work of Professor Boyd show that "This shows that products, as well as sums, of fractional positive powers of posynomials can be handled.". However, this case is much more complicated because the power is negative. For example ${\left( {{x_1} + {x_2} + {x_3}} \right)^{ - 1}}$.
Would you kindly help me with this ?
Thank you for your enthusiasm !

what's the motivation of converting a linear constraint to GP one?

Well I have an optimization poblem with a mixed of posynomial term and linear constraint so it seems that GP is the way to go

Try a transformaton on the variable,  $\bar{x}_i = 1-x_i$,
From $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i \ge 1$,
$$\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{x}_i = \sum_{i=1}^n (1-x_i) = n-\sum_{i=1}^nx_i\le n-1$$
$$\frac1{n-1}\sum_{i=1}^n \bar{x}_i \le 1$$

Are there any way to tackle this constraint directly, it seems very GP to me ${\left( {{x_1} + {x_2} + ... + {x_n}} \right)^{ - 1}} \le 1$ ?

hmm... can't think of a method for now.

The constraint $\bar{x}_i = 1-x_i$ is not allowed in geometric programming. So this would only work if this substitution could be used everywhere, i.e., so that $x_i$ would not be an optimization variable at all, and $\bar{x}_i$ would be in the model instead of $x_i$.

that's true, other any other constraints?
